# In Rails 3.2, update_all query statement is not updating 'updated_at' column in database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
EmailBulk.where(id: params[:email_bulk][:id]).update_all(html_content: params[:email_bulk][:html_content], subject: params[:email_bulk][:subject])
```

statement does not update email_bulk.updated_at column ? why? Should I send the time also like this

```
EmailBulk.where(id: params[:email_bulk][:id]).update_all(html_content: params[:email_bulk][:html_content], subject: params[:email_bulk][:subject], updated_at: Datetime.now.utc )
```

if so? How can I create DateTime in the format at which active record creates say: 2015-01-06 06:44:55 . I prefer not hard coding the time and formats

Answer (score 1):

Updates all, This method constructs a single SQL UPDATE statement and sends it straight to the database. It does not instantiate the involved models and it does not trigger Active Record callbacks or validations. Values passed to `update_all` will not go through ActiveRecord's type-casting behavior. It should receive only values that can be passed as-is to the SQL database.

As such, it does not trigger callbacks nor validations - and timestamp update is made in a callback.update_at is a call back